# Not able to disable SUFFIXES in makefile

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html#Suffix-Rules):

> If you wish to eliminate the default known suffixes instead of just
>   adding to them, write a rule for '.SUFFIXES' with no prerequisites.  By
>   special dispensation, this eliminates all existing prerequisites of
>   '.SUFFIXES'.  You can then write another rule to add the suffixes you
>   want.  For example,
>
> ```
>  .SUFFIXES:            # Delete the default suffixes
>  .SUFFIXES: .c .o .h   # Define our suffix list
> ```

Trying the following makefile:

```
.c.o:
    @echo done

.SUFFIXES::

all.o: phony

all.c:

.PHONY: phony
```

Running Make, i get:

```
done
```

Even though, I disabled suffixes, by `.SUFFIXES::`.

By the way, for some reason, it works in version 3.81, where I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all.o'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says: `.SUFFIXES:`

You wrote: `.SUFFIXES::`

Remove the extra colon and it will work.